# Unresolved external symbol (LNK2001)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have two projects: Project A and project B.

Project B references Project A.

When I compile I get the following errors:

```
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/MaxILKSize:2146435072'; ignored
1>Testing.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_ITestIntOne
1>Testing.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_ITestIntTwo
1>Testing.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_WTest
1>    Wait PDB close: Total time = 0.000s
1>  Final: Total time = 1.547s
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

However project B is not using the `SecurityCenterIntegration` class at all, so I'm not sure why there are problems while linking to it.

Comment: I guess it is visual studio(add tag?), but which version? plus, it looks like a COM symbols. is one of the projects is COM?

Comment: @SHR VS2013 and no Project A is a static lib but using COM components which are declared in another lib.

Comment: I guess what you missing is the com lib, you cant add it to the static lib, you should add it to the executable.

Comment: One more question: I guess you use `import` to use the COM. what about the generated files?does your static lib project contain them?

Comment: @SHR The generated files are included in project A in the ...stdafx.h file I have tried this in Project B but no luck... I think there is a lib missing in the additionaloptions tag just saw a difference by comparing two vcxproj files... do you know where the additional options tag is on VS2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing Project A's libs or sources. Make sure you included all dependencies in the project settings. Go to Properties > Linker > General and check Additional Library Directories are correct. Also add any additional libs and objs into Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for this, one quick question.. in vcproj files there is an additional options tag... do you know where to find this in the project properties in VS2013

Comment: You can find it under Properties > C/C++ > All Options > Additional Options