# Progamming Principles and Practice using C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup , chapter 12 : A Display Model , First example

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I'm currently reading Progamming Principles and Practice using C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup . And I'm trying to code this example in the book.

```
#include "Simple_window.h"
#include "Graph.h"
int main()
{
         using namespace Graph_lib;
          Point tl(100,100); 
         Simple_window win(tl,600,400,"Canvas"); 
         Polygon poly;
         poly.add(Point(300,200));
         poly.add(Point(350,100));
         poly.add(Point(400,200));
         poly.set_color(Color::red);
         win.attach (poly);
         win.wait_for_button();
}
```

I debugged and it gave out these lines :

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Graph_lib::Window::Window(struct Graph_lib::Point,int,int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0Window@Graph_lib@@QEAA@UPoint@1@HHAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)  WindowsProject5 E:\Visual C++\WindowsProject5\WindowsProject5.obj   1   

Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl Graph_lib::Window::attach(class Graph_lib::Widget &)" (?attach@Window@Graph_lib@@QEAAXAEAVWidget@2@@Z) WindowsProject5 E:\Visual C++\WindowsProject5\WindowsProject5.obj   1   

Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl Graph_lib::Window::attach(class Graph_lib::Shape &)" (?attach@Window@Graph_lib@@QEAAXAEAVShape@2@@Z)   WindowsProject5 E:\Visual C++\WindowsProject5\WindowsProject5.obj   1   

Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl Graph_lib::Polygon::add(struct Graph_lib::Point)" (?add@Polygon@Graph_lib@@QEAAXUPoint@2@@Z)   WindowsProject5 E:\Visual C++\WindowsProject5\WindowsProject5.obj   1   

Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl Graph_lib::Shape::move(int,int)" (?move@Shape@Graph_lib@@UEAAXHH@Z)    WindowsProject5 E:\Visual C++\WindowsProject5\WindowsProject5.obj   1   

Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl Graph_lib::Polygon::draw_lines(void)const " (?draw_lines@Polygon@Graph_lib@@UEBAXXZ)   WindowsProject5 E:\Visual C++\WindowsProject5\WindowsProject5.obj   1   

Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl Graph_lib::Open_polyline::draw_lines(void)const " (?draw_lines@Open_polyline@Graph_lib@@UEBAXXZ)   WindowsProject5 E:\Visual C++\WindowsProject5\WindowsProject5.obj   1   

Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl Graph_lib::Closed_polyline::draw_lines(void)const " (?draw_lines@Closed_polyline@Graph_lib@@UEBAXXZ)   WindowsProject5 E:\Visual C++\WindowsProject5\WindowsProject5.obj   1   

Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl Graph_lib::Button::attach(class Graph_lib::Window &)" (?attach@Button@Graph_lib@@UEAAXAEAVWindow@2@@Z) WindowsProject5 E:\Visual C++\WindowsProject5\WindowsProject5.obj   1   

Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl Graph_lib::Window::draw(void)" (?draw@Window@Graph_lib@@MEAAXXZ)    WindowsProject5 E:\Visual C++\WindowsProject5\WindowsProject5.obj   1   

Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl Graph_lib::Shape::draw_lines(void)const " (?draw_lines@Shape@Graph_lib@@MEBAXXZ)    WindowsProject5 E:\Visual C++\WindowsProject5\WindowsProject5.obj   1?
```

I tried but still can not solve it . Can anyone help me with this problem ? Really appreciate .                                                                                 Sorry my English is not so good.

Comment: This is **not** C, but C++, so I'm happy someone removed that tag. Don't "randomly" use tags. Also, this doesn't compile because `poly.set_color(Color: : red);` isn't valid syntax.

Comment: Please make sure the code in this question is **exactly** the same code you are compiling.  The code `Color: : red` would not lead to the linker errors you are showing.

Comment: I'm sure that this's exactly the same as the code I'm compiling .

Comment: @MarcusMüller I should have check the tag before I posted it . I will be more carefull next time .

Comment: @MarcusMüller  ``` poly.set_color(Color: : red); ``` is valid  . The compiler gives no error message about that line .

Comment: This looks like a project configuration error. You need to specify where the `Graph_lib` library file is to your compiler.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux can you tell me how to do it ?

Comment: @B20DCCN177-PhùngVănĐạt Does this answer your question? [Unresolved external symbol (LNK2001)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938862/unresolved-external-symbol-lnk2001) Searching for "Stack Overflow [your error code]" will frequently provide you with a solution for your problem.

Comment: @B20DCCN177-PhùngVănĐạt I'm sure it's not the code you're compiling, because what you posted would fail to compile, as `Color:` is not a primary expression, which you would need before a `:` leading up to your red.

Comment: not to mention that your `ti` comes out of nowhere, as well.

Comment: This example program is in many Stack Overflow questions, except for `Color: : red`, which all the other questions have as `Color::red`, as if using the `::` scope resolution operator.

Comment: @MarcusMüller My mistake , sorry .